# Point custom domain to single webpage hosted on Dropbox

Tags: domains, dns, google-index, cloud-hosting, dropbox

I have a static html page that I would like to host in Dropbox's public folder and make accessible by a domain of mine, e.g `example.org`.

The html page has the following url structure `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/user_nubmer/folder_name/index.html`

Is it possible to point a custom domain to a url (such as above) and:
A) have the domain persist in the address bar
B) make the content indexable by search engines

Comment: It would only be possible if DropBox added a feature to use custom domains which I believe they don't, through you can use their Api but you would still need a domain + own hosting to use, you can redirect but the address bar will change, there's no real way around that other than using a iframe but again, you need your own hosting, other solutions include: http://www.maketecheasier.com/4-ways-to-host-your-website-on-dropbox/

Comment: Did you wish/intend to do this using your own web hosting, or were you hoping to do this without any web hosting required beyond what Dropbox provide?

Comment: The latter. As I only have a single html page it feels like such an overhead to sign up for standard web hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Frames!

You can search for a free host (such as 000webhost, HostYD or Hostinger) and create a page with the following content:

```
<iframe src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/user_nubmer/folder_name/index.html" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
  Your browser doesn't support IFrames
</iframe>`
```

As you can see, it loads the content from `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/user_nubmer/folder_name/index.html`.

Point your domain to the free web host and it'll load the Dropbox file from a frame.

You said you don't want to use hosting, but well... I couldn't think of another way, so you'll be better off by doing this ^

Comment: If I sign upp an account at a web host, I don't see the point why not have the html file there as well. And besides, I'm not sure Google would index iframed content.

Comment: @Numbers >> I don't see the point why not have the html file there as well. - Exactly, I don't either... >> And besides, I'm not sure Google would index iframed content. - It does, why not?

Comment: A fast Google search educated me that Google wouldn't, but if your experience is the opposite, then well good!

Comment: Google would index the iframe content but under the domain from which it is obtained (dl.dropboxusercontent.com) not under example.org. To see example listings, enter "site:dl.dropboxusercontent.com" into the Google search box.

Comment: @Numbers Weird... my sites with frames were always indexed :)